# How to create Monaco Editor custom language in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, monaco-editor

I have tried to create custom language with auto complete ( intellisenses ). It's not working out. can  any one help me to achieve this.

Code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-emjqsr?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: check this guide https://github.com/atularen/ngx-monaco-editor#readme

Comment: @PedroB. Yeah i have checked this documentaion already. similar way only developed. I want have custom langauage with intellisenses (custom suggesstions). can you please provice any example related to custom language and intellisenses(suggesstions)

Comment: maybe this https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages ?

Comment: @PedroB. I need anguar examples with ngx directive not in javascript.  This example i had look earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there.

You only need to return object like `{ suggestions: suggestions }` instead of array in your `provideCompletionItems` method and you're done:

```
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('dummy', {
  provideCompletionItems: () => {
    var suggestions = [
      {
        label: 'simpleText',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Text,
        insertText: 'simpleText',
      },
      {
        label: 'testing',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
        insertText: 'testing(${1:condition})',
        insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,
      },
      {
        label: 'ifelse',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Snippet,
        insertText: ['if (${1:condition}) {', '\t$0', '} else {', '\t', '}'].join('\n'),
        insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,
        documentation: 'If-Else Statement',
      },
    ];
    return { suggestions: suggestions };
  },
});
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/AcXqMyl9Jqa2Jj2eYSRh?open=app%2Fmonaco-config.ts&layout=1)**

Comment: I need your help. My requirement is when i will type simpleText(consider as a tableName) and then when i type colon(:) it has to list our attributes belongs to simpleText table. let's say ( one, two, three ) need to display. can you help me to achieve this. I tried it's not working with mupltiple values(attributes)

Comment: Awaiting for your answer on above requirement

Comment: Can you please update